# Getting an error: "Has no exported member AngularFire, AuthProviders, AUthMethods, FirebaseListObservable" in AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angularfire2

I am new to Angular 4, so I am creating a firebase chat app with Angular 4, and then when I import some modules like this:

```
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods,FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
```

I get an error for each module that says

> Has no exported member AngularFire, AuthProviders, AUthMethods, FirebaseListObservable.

Thank you

Comment: what's you version of angulafire2?

Comment: angularfire2 -v does not work. do you know how to check for the version?

Comment: check your local package.json or `package,json` in `angularfire2`.

Comment: the version is 4.0.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UP TO DATE(Ver 5.0.0-rc3):**

While getting this error, this means you are using old Database API. This can solved by importing `FirebaseListObservable` from **depracated** module(See also **@Ashish Jha** answer):

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```

**It's recommended to use the latest API since AngularFire 5.0 brings new API for the Realtime Database. Refer upgrade [guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md).**

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
AngularFire2 has separate its modules since 4.0.0+.

you can import those two module if you want use auth of angularfire2, see their change [log](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md) :

```
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
// for auth    
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
// for database
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

and import `Auth` and `Observable`(AuthMethods can be found in AngularFireAuth) type by:

```
// for auth
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
// for database
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angular2/database';
// for Observables
import {FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Comment: How about the rest, that is shown in my question. Now, FirebaseListObservable has exported, but the rest "AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods" are not exported. And Also, when I hit ng serve in terminal to see my app. I get an error: "The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed."

Comment: With a little effort you can find those others now too... Just look in the changelog provided here. The angular compiler-cli you can install like: npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli

Comment: @stevenvanc when doing "npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli " I get UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler.

Comment: @Pengyy is getting a UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler

Comment: @Jośe run `npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli` too. also when you are done with your project run `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` too

Comment: @Pengyy Update your answer ASAP, its not working for the latest version.  This is more preferable import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";

Comment: @Rijo thanks for your comment. In order to not confuse others who are looking for help here with old version, I just updated to include the deprecated version and also add a upgrade guide for the latest version of angularfire2.

Comment: Okay, I am using "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3" for this i can't import import {FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database'; showing as error

Comment: @Rijo see my **up to date** part. You should import them from `angularfire2/database-deprecated`.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that worked for me was to change this line

```
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods,FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
```

to

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
```

You can read more about it here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: ahhhrrr!! all those too fast changes..... same mess with firebase, same mess with material. THX ALOT

Comment: You're welcome. The new update uses AngularFirestore and it uses a simple Observable instead of FirebaseListObservable. This thing bugged me for quite a bit too.

Answer (score 0):

use AngularFireObject instead of FirebaseObjectObservable and AngularFireList instead of FirebaseListObservable ,this has been updated since AngularFire5

if you want more details checkout
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).