# import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database";

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

i had problem to

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database";
```

i imported AngularFireDatabase but FirebaseListObservable was under a red line after searching 
this post helped me resolve my problem 
[Getting an error: "Has no exported member AngularFire, AuthProviders, AUthMethods, FirebaseListObservable" in AngularFire2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990887/getting-an-error-has-no-exported-member-angularfire-authproviders-authmethod)

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
```

but when i compile i get and it cant help i dont know what to do where searching ect
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!
Error: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!

"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "^4.5.0",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.2 you can't use FirebaseListObservable instead you will have to use

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

and use it like this

```
constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
  let restaurants = this.af.list('/path');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

i got the answer  after reading https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md 
5.0.0-rc.0 (2017-10-03)

the -deprecated allows you to use the old database API

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```

in the app.module.js
and in your service you use

```
 import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
```

thank you both of you, you helped me

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the following and add it under your app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: which config? did you add it to your module?

Comment: BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,   
    AngularFireAuthModule, 
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772474/no-provider-for-angularfiredatabase-angularfireauth

Answer (score 0):

You can't use FirebaseListObservable in current version of angularfire2.
It worked in old version of angularfire2 like 4.0.0-rc.1.

So, install it and it will work totally fine (in terminal):

`npm i angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1`

and import:

```
import {AngularFireDatabase,FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be late, but in case anyone still wonders what they can use as an alternative, note that `FirebaseListObservable` has been deprecated.

However, in the latest version of firebase note that you can use `AngularFireList`, and import it as so...

`import { AngularFireDatabase , AngularFireList} from '@angular/fire/database';`