# Angular and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to make a project on angular and with firebase. I have installed firebase using cli command "npm install firebse angularfire2 --save". When I am importing FirebaseListObservable I am getting an error.
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';`
This is a service.
Here is the Component file.

```js
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyD8cYGy1sth5-BPkcB_yksZdZWQkcAnpXk",
    authDomain: "clientpanel-9f785.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://clientpanel-9f785.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "clientpanel-9f785",
    storageBucket: "clientpanel-9f785.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "296835281822"
}
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AddClientComponent,
    ClientDetailsComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ClientsComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    EditClientComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    SettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ClientService,
    AngularFireAuth,
    AngularFireDatabase
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: No imported membor FirebaseListObservable in 'databse/index'

Comment: you should at least remove `AngularFireAuth, AngularFireDatabase` from the providers list. These are provided through the imports. Also the `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` is unnecessary

Comment: Okay.But still I am getting that error.

Comment: Which rxjs version you have and which version of firebase and angularfire2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';`

instead of

`import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';`

Which version do you use? In AngularFire 5.0 FirebaseListObservable is removed

Answer (score 0):

```
  providers: [
    ClientService,
    AngularFireAuth, // Delete
    AngularFireDatabase // Delete
  ],
```

You dont use `AngularFireAuth` and `AngularFireDatabase` in AppModule. You use them in your services or components, something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class AppComponent {
    public books: FirebaseListObservable<Book[]>;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.books = db.list('/books');
    }
}
```

Read [this](https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-firebase-typescript-step-by-step-tutorial-2ef887fc7d71) tutorial for more information

**Update**

I don't know with version you are using but follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990887/getting-an-error-has-no-exported-member-angularfire-authproviders-authmethod), if you using AngularFire v5

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```

Comment: I tried that but still getting the error.Is there any way to upgrade firebase2 version using cli

Comment: {
 "resource": "/e:/Angular/clientpanel/src/app/app.component.ts",
 "owner": "typescript",
 "code": "2305",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Module '\"e:/Angular/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index\"' has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.",
This is the problem I am getting.

Comment: @TirthTrivedi `npm install angularfire2@latest --save` or unintall angularfire2 `npm uninstall angularfire2 --save` and install version you want `npm install angularfire2@versionyouwant --save`