# Firebase with angular 6 imports problems?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angular6

I am creating user registration system using google firebase , I am following this tutorial :

[User registration system](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/32/Create-a-Full-Angular-Authentication-System-with-Firebase)

**NOTE**

> : am using this version   "firebase": "^5.5.6",

When I run my app I have the following errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/jelly/projects/profile/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFire'.
src/app/login/login.component.ts(3,28): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/jelly/projects/profile/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/index"' has no exported member 'AuthProviders'.
src/app/login/login.component.ts(3,43): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/jelly/projects/profile/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/index"' has no exported member 'AuthMethods'.
```

Here is app.modul.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from './service/user.service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MomentModule } from 'ngx-moment';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { EmailComponent } from './email/email.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';



const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: ''
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    EmailComponent,
    SignupComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MomentModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is login component other components right just empyt

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestore, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  // declare empyt array to hold error data
  error: any;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {

  // fucntion to check user authentication
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/members');
      }
    });
   }

  // function to login in facebook
  loginFb() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    }).then(
      (success) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/members']);
    }).catch(
      (err) => {
        this.error = this.error;
      });
  }

    // function to login with google
    loginGoogle() {
      this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup,
      }).then(
        (success) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/members']);
      }).catch(
        (err) => {
          this.error = this.error;
        });
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have used almost all solution in stack overflow but nothing worked , I am about to give up now , I dont see any good documentation on this for dummies to understand what the hell is going on  :(

What do I need to change to get rid of this error?? please help

Comment: which firebase release do you use ?

Comment: @Jake11    "firebase": "^5.5.6",

Comment: so version they used in tut is ~3.6.5, you can try to downgrade to it, or try to follow releases notes https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js to find out where those classes has been moved, or just search in docs where can you  find them for version that you are using.

Comment: if you decide to downgrade  i am not sure but you propably will have to also downgrade angularfire2 to older version

Comment: umfortunately downgrading the firebase still have errors and many others erros comes in

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial is from  Jan 17, 2017 and if you run `npm install angularfire2 firebase --save` you will have latest version of firebase installed, which is not the one tutorial is based on, look here is [similar post on this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990887/getting-an-error-has-no-exported-member-angularfire-authproviders-authmethod)

So you have to etiher downgrade firebase version, which you use for this project or upgrade imports so their point to right files, in which you can find classes you need

Comment: jake I tried all this souliton but none works :( that is why I needed some help

Comment: @user9964622 and whats version of angularfire2 do you have ?

Comment: "angularfire2": "^5.1.0",?

Comment: @user9964622 run `npm remove angularfire2` -> `npm install angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.7 --save` -> `npm remove firebase` -> `npm install firebase@3.6.5 --save` -> restart app -> tell me if error is still occuring

Comment: now I get this error : `'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.`

Comment: update whole package.json so it looks same as here https://github.com/designcourse/angular-auth-demo/blob/master/package.json , run `npm update`, and restart project, try `npm install` if `npm update` wont help